# How to limit secure protocol in wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, security, ssl

I need to write WCF service using TLS 1.2.I need to use only this security protocol and (as i think) refuse connections with other secure protocol types. I have created certificate. Bind it to port. Https works well. I read everywhere that i need to write next string of code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Ok, i wrote it, but had no effect. Service side code:

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using static System.Console;

namespace ConsoleHost
{

    public class DistributorValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                throw new SecurityTokenException("Both username and password required");
            if (userName != "login" || password != "pass")
                throw new FaultException($"Wrong username ({userName}) or password ");
        }
    }

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return $"You entered: {value}";
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(composite));
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue { get; set; } = true;

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue { get; set; } = "Hello ";
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
            host.Open();
            WriteLine("Press any key to stop server...");
            ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

App.config contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>

  <system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="ConsoleHost.Service1">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress = "https://localhost:8734/Service1/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ConsoleHost.IService1" bindingConfiguration="securityBinding">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="securityBinding">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          <!--establishSecurityContext="false" />-->
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        <serviceCredentials>
          <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="ConsoleHost.DistributorValidator,ConsoleHost"/>
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Client side code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
                Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "login";
                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
                Console.WriteLine(client.GetData(10));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    if (ex.InnerException.InnerException != null)
                        Console.WriteLine("Inner: " + ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see on service side i have set security protocol to Tls 1.2. On client side i have set security protocol to Ssl3. I am waiting that service will refuse client connection, because server must work and accept clients who will work with only Tls 1.2 security protocol. But i'm not getting this result. Client connects and works well. What's the problem?

I understand that i can change some settings on IIS to use only Tls 1.2. But i am making self hosting wcf service and that's the problem.

Comment: There is no connection between your `ServicePointManager` object and the WCF service/client that I can see.  I'm not sure how you would connect the two, but as your current posted code shows, you're not assigning the protocol to any particular URI.

Comment: @Tim, I've set baseaddress in app.config. And service using this URI. How can i set connection between ServicePointManager and my WCF service? As i know ServicePointManager influences on all connections in the current AppDomain. Is it wrong?

Comment: I'm looking at the same issue. Everyone recommends setting the System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol property, but it's not clear where and when to do that in a WCF Service (regular type, not console host), and there's no mention of how to do it properly in the config file.

Comment: @PJ7, absolutely agree. I still have no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done for server using ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol option, that's used to connection to sth through a specific security protocol. You can't turn off some security protocol for an separate application, you able to allow or dissallow connections for whole server. If u want disable all protocols except TLS 1.2 u have to open registry windows and find out the next key:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\
```

And set the next values for each protocol in key [Server]: DisabledByDefault = 1, Enabled = 0

[How to enable TLS](https://basics.net/2015/10/06/iis-7-5-how-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/)